# Expandable List view with different children

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I am trying to make the last child of every group and edit text and a button. I am using a custom ExpandableListViewAdapter. This is what I have so far.

```
  public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Children, null);
        }
        if (isLastChild==true)
        {
            EditText Submit = convertView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Submit);
            Button button = convertView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button);
            TextView textViewItem = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataValue);
            textViewItem.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }

        else {
            TextView textViewItem = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataValue);
            EditText Submit = convertView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Submit);
            Button button = convertView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button);
            button.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            Submit.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            string content = (string)GetChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            textViewItem.Text = content;
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

This helps put a EditText and Button but only in the first group while also cutting off some of the children in the first group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This helps put a EditText and Button but only in the first group while also cutting off some of the children in the first group.

`ExpandableListView` reuses the childview, so if you want the last line to be your button and edittext, you need to set it to visible explicitly. Just add three lines of codes to your `GetChildView` method:

```
public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Children, null);
    }
    if (isLastChild == true)
    {
        EditText Submit = convertView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Submit);
        Button button = convertView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button);

        //add below two lines to your codes
        Submit.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        button.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        TextView textViewItem = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataValue);
        textViewItem.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    }
    else
    {
        TextView textViewItem = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DataValue);
        EditText Submit = convertView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Submit);
        Button button = convertView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button);
        button.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        Submit.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        //also add below line of codes
        textViewItem.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        string content = (string)GetChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        textViewItem.Text = content;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: This works great for having it at the bottom, but once I open up a group with less children, the group with more children ends up deleting some of the info. When I open more than one group it also gets rid of some of the children! not sure what is going on here!

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the `textViewItem`. You also need to explicitly set the `textViewItem.Visiblity` to visible. I've updated the answer ,please have a check.

Comment: Thank you so much! That will be all the bother for now! I kept getting close, just was off by a bit  but with your help I got it good!

Comment: Xia, I was wondering if you can help me with my expand problem... No one is answering yet and you can be of the most help. I can not find anything online and the android database doesnt have enough info.